# Redirect domain.me.com.au to domain.me.com.au/text

Tags: linux, virtualhost, httpd

I am using httpd Version:2.4.6 to this what I have tried using vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     Servername domain.me.com.au
     RedirectMatch permanent (.*) https://domain.me.com.au/text$1
</virtualHost>
```

But I am getting an error page saying that the page has redirected too many times can I get help on this please?

Comment: What are you trying to redirect? Just the homepage? As it stands, you're redirecting every page on the site, including the `/text` page itself: it continually redirects to itself, hence the warning.

Comment: Please be aware that a **Permanent Redirect** (a redirect with HTTP response code 301) is exactly that: permanent. Such a redirect will be cached by all common web browsers. - If you made a mistake in your server configuration and don't clear your caches (or don't do each new test in a new anonymous/incognito/private window) then any changes you make in the server configuration won't become apparent as your webbrowser will both use the stale cached redirect and change the request you enter in the URL bar for you even before it gets sent to a server.

Comment: Your syntax appears essentially correct to Redirect your plain http site to the secure https version and to insert the base path /text/ in existing URL's but you don't happen to be behind cloudflare or a similar reverse proxy? A fairly typical problem is that you forward both the plain http and the https version of your site from your CDN CloudFlare to a http only back end. Even when the client uses https it will only be between their browser and cloudflare.
When on your server you try to enforce https that can never happen and you will get too many redirects.